# Disable "drag" function for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avkit

My app plays videos for toddlers. It uses AVPlayer. In a recent update Apple has implemented the function of dragging the video view to close it. This doesn't work well with toddlers touching the screen all the time.

Does anyone know how to disable this function? (the code is in Objective-C)

Comment: Hi @Emily94, Haven't you found any result?

Answer (score 0):

I have no ready solution but I will try to point you into some directions you could try.

Have you tried to use `AVPlayerViewController` along with the delegate `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` with the method `playerViewControllerShouldDismiss(AVPlayerViewController)`, it maybe works for your case.

As a last resort you would need to implement AVLayerPlayer and provide the UI yourself.